# Can a matlab function called within a script cause the script to break?

Tags: matlab, function, return, break

I am running a script which calls a function, and if a certain condition is met, inside the function, I want the whole thing just to terminate (and by that I do not mean I want to close matlab using `exit`). Is that possible? I know I can use `return` or `break` to return to the script, however I want the script to stop as well if this condition is met.

Comment: Look at `error`

Comment: you can always check the output of your function and determine whether your function has run to an end or it returns at the middle of its execution. You can also assign an output variable specifically for returning at a certain line and check the variable in your main script to stop your script using `return` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

The only function I know of that does this is `error`. This throws an exception, and, if no exception handlers with `try` and `catch` are installed in the calling script, will terminate and return to command prompt. Which is what you want, as far as I understand. It prints an error message though. This could be suppressed if you guard all code in the top-level script with a try catch handler. However this will have to be specific to the one error and it makes debugging ("stop-on-error") much more difficult.

The thing is that the only use case I see for this behavior (termination of whole program on certain event) is when a non recoverable error occurs, and in that case printing an error message is indeed appropriate.

In case the script is successful termination of the whole program is not really the right way. All functions should return to give the upper layers of the code to perform some clean-up action, like saving the output data or so.

Comment: @Adriaan: hmm, but not within the same script. After the error printing everything is terminated. I dont see how this could work.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: yes, but then the debugger stops at every exception also those which are normally hidden by `try` `catch`  You typically get a multitude of hits, e.g. from MATLAB internal code, but also when debugging GUI code. I used it a few times, but try to avoid it whenever possible.